# NSKeyed archiver warnings using unique keys

Tags: ios, objective-c, state-restoration

I am getting multiple log warnings like this when I put my app into the background using the home button when testing preservation / state restoration.

```
2014-02-13 20:13:08.275 FlowTrak[16777:60b] *** NSKeyedArchiver warning: replacing existing 
value for key 'UIStateRestorationViewControllerStoryboard'; probable duplication of encoding 
keys in class hierarchy
```

The app runs fine on the device, and all of the state restoration / preservation works as it should, but I would love to get rid of these warnings. There is not a ton of info about these warnings out there, but from what I have read, I should be good to go so long as I am using unique keys for each UI item I am preserving.

Any ideas on sorting this out? Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
// Restoration of text fields
-(void)encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    // start level text
    [coder encodeObject:_startLevel.text forKey:@"startText"];
    [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // stop level text
    [coder encodeObject:_stopLevel.text forKey:@"stopText"];
    [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // start time label
    [coder encodeObject:_startTimeLabel.text forKey:@"startTimeText"];
    [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // stop time label
    [coder encodeObject:_stopTimeLabel.text forKey:@"stopTimeText"];
    [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // minute rate label
    [coder encodeObject:_minuteRateLabel.text forKey:@"minuteRateText"];
    [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // start segmented control
    [coder encodeInteger:self.startFractionControl.selectedSegmentIndex forKey:@"startIndex"];
    [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // stop segmented control
    [coder encodeInteger:self.stopFractionControl.selectedSegmentIndex forKey:@"stopIndex"];
    [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // start button state
    [coder encodeBool:self.start.enabled forKey:@"startButtonState"];
    [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // stop button state
    [coder encodeBool:self.stop.enabled forKey:@"stopButtonState"];
    [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // calculate button state
    [coder encodeBool:self.calculate.enabled forKey:@"calculateButtonState"];
    [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // resume button state
    [coder encodeBool:self.resume.enabled forKey:@"resumeButtonState"];
    [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // tank selector segmented control
    [coder encodeInteger:self.tankControl.selectedSegmentIndex forKey:@"tankIndex"];
    [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // start time for equation
    [coder encodeDouble:startTime forKey:@"startTimeEquation"];
    [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // stop time for equation
    [coder encodeDouble:stopTime forKey:@"stopTimeEquation"];
    [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // start segmented control for equation
    [coder encodeObject:startFractions forKey:@"startFractionsEquation"];
    [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // stop segmented control for equation
    [coder encodeObject:stopFractions forKey:@"stopFractionsEquation"];
    [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // tank selector segmented control for equation
    [coder encodeBool:bigTank forKey:@"bigTankEquation"];
    [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];


}

-(void)decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    // start level text
    _startLevel.text = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"startText"];
    [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // stop level text
    _stopLevel.text = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"stopText"];
    [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // start time label
    _startTimeLabel.text = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"startTimeText"];
    [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // stop time label
    _stopTimeLabel.text = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"stopTimeText"];
    [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // minute rate label
    _minuteRateLabel.text = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"minuteRateText"];
    [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // start segmented control
     self.startFractionControl.selectedSegmentIndex = [coder decodeIntegerForKey:@"startIndex"];
    [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // stop segmented control
    self.stopFractionControl.selectedSegmentIndex = [coder decodeIntegerForKey:@"stopIndex"];
    [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // start button state
    self.start.enabled = [coder decodeBoolForKey:@"startButtonState"];
    [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // stop button state
    self.stop.enabled = [coder decodeBoolForKey:@"stopButtonState"];
    [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // calculate button state
    self.calculate.enabled = [coder decodeBoolForKey:@"calculateButtonState"];
    [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // resume button state
    self.resume.enabled = [coder decodeBoolForKey:@"resumeButtonState"];
    [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // tank selector segmented control
    self.tankControl.selectedSegmentIndex = [coder decodeIntegerForKey:@"tankIndex"];
    [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // start time for equation
    startTime = [coder decodeDoubleForKey:@"startTimeEquation"];
    [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // stop time for equation
    stopTime = [coder decodeDoubleForKey:@"stopTimeEquation"];
    [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // start segmented control for equation
    startFractions = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"startFractionsEquation"];
    [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // stop segmented control for equation
    stopFractions = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"stopFractionsEquation"];
    [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // calculate button state
    bigTank = [coder decodeBoolForKey:@"bigTankEquation"];
    [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you calling super's implementation multiple times? Only call it once!